# How to getParcelableExtra in Recieving activity without finishing it

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

Suppose, I have 1st `activity`, from which I go to the 2nd `activity` without finishing the 1st `activity`.

when I press the back button in 2nd `activity` , I came back to 1st activity finishing the 2nd activity & setting values in parcel class with constructor.
If I use `startActivity()` in 2nd activity , then it's works fine, but I just want to use `finish()` in 2nd activity.

Now, I want to `getParcelableExtra()` in my 1st activity.

how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you should try startActivityForResult() and get whatever your result you want

Comment: @MohitSuthar thank you. I am using parcel class for passing data from activities, If I use startActivityForResult(), then I don't need to use parcel class, right? but unfortunately , I need to use parcel class.

Comment: if you are passing data using parcel class than you can get parsing data using startActivityForResult(), if you know how to use startActivityForResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 1st activity call

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(context, YourSecondActivity.class), requestCode);
```

In your 2nd activity you can override `onBackPressed()` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("extra_name", YourParcelable);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Then, in the 1st activity receive parcelable data:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    YourClass value = (YourClass)data.getParcelableExtra("extra_name");
}
```